# Can't find UIButton within view - Appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios

Alright, so I'm using Appium to automate some tasks within an app I work on for my company. I have a stackview within a tableviewcell and then within that stackview I have two labels a button. When I open Appium inspector it finds both labels and the button. Enabled and visible is set to true on my labels, but on my button only enabled is set to true while visible is set to false. The button isn't in any other view, so I'm confused on why Appium can't find this button. The accessibility ID is set and the Appium inspector shows that and I've tried setting isAccessible on the button, but no luck. Any thoughts?

```
public void selectRatingWithStar(int numOfClicks, int position){
    System.out.println("before driver");
    new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(completeDocumentationButton)));
    System.out.println("after driver");
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfClicks; i++){
        completeDocumentationButton.get(position).click();
    }
}
```

[Appium Inspector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrIWM.png)

Comment: Take a screenshot of your Appium Inspector with the element in question selected, make sure we can see the properties, add it to your original post.  It would also be useful to see what code you've written.

Comment: @BillHileman Done! I couldn't post the screen shot of the actual application screen due to company privacy.

Comment: That does help some, but it doesn't show if the button has a unique ID like resource-id or not.  Are you using the suggested xpath locator?  It does indicate that the button highlighted is the first of multiple buttons.  I assume that completeDocumentationButton is List of type MobileElement or similar?  Using that xpath, minus the [1]?  Also, are ALL buttons visible at once?

Comment: completeDocumentationButton is a UIButton, not a list type. I just tried this code: `@iOSFindBy(xpath = "(//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"completionButton\"])")`

Comment: And got this error: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for condition (visibility of all [[[iOS: null] -> xpath: (//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="completionButton"])], [[iOS: null] -> xpath: (//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="completionButton"])], [[iOS: null] -> xpath: (//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="completionButton"])], [[iOS: null] -> xpath: (//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="completionButton"])], [[iOS: null] -> xpath: (//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="completionButton"])]]) to be refreshed (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)`

Comment: I'm confused on what you're asking here: "Also, are ALL buttons visible at once?" At no point are these buttons ever hidden on this screen.

Comment: I'll have to reply later, sorry - heading home from work.

Comment: @BillHileman no problem.

Comment: I'd leave the outside parentheses out of the xpath, and the "[1]" indicates to me that there are multiple instances of that particular xpath, so you should be assigning the result to a list of webelements, or more specifically a list of mobileelements.  You might only see one button, but there may be more in the DOM that are not visible.  Try `xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='completionButton']"` assign it to a `List<MobileElement>` and access it via `list.get(1)`

Comment: Still nothing. Here is the code:
`@iOSFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='completionButton']")
    private List<WebElement> completeDocumentationButton;` and the execution of the driver
`new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(completeDocumentationButton)));`
Appium desktop is still showing the elements visibility property as false.

Comment: What does `completeDocumentationButton.size()` return?  Have you tried accessing the elements without the wait?  Are you using pagefactory?

Comment: When I accessed the size I got: 5. When I used this code `List<MobileElement> elementsOne = driver.findElementsByAccessibilityId("completionButton");
        System.out.println("This element:" + elementsOne.get(1));` instead of the waitdriver I got this: `[[iOS: null] -> accessibility id: completionButton]`

Comment: And yes, I am using pagefactory. I think it may have to do with how I'm displaying the buttons. I'll try a few things in our code base and come back here if anything. Thank you so much for all your help! If you have any other suggestions I'm all ears.